# An invertible matrix maps vectors in a subspace to a subspace of the same number of dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\text{G}_{n,k}$ denote the set of all $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
If $W\in \text{G}_{n,k}$ and $A\in \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$, define
$$A\cdot W=\{Aw:w\in W\}$$
Show that $A\cdot W\in \text{G}_{n,k}$.
I think I understand this intuitively, in the sense that if our matrix $A$ is invertible, then it's action on a vector will preserve it's dimensions. But, I can't seem to write it in mathematical a language.

Comment: Show that $A\cdot W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ which is isomorphic to $W$. Alternatively, you can choose a basis of $W$ and use it to find a basis of $A\cdot W$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the help.